# List of users of packaged app

Tags: google-chrome-app

Aside from installing google analytics and outright asking users to send their name and users, is there any way to get a list of all the users who installed my (free) app?

The google chrome webstore dashboard only shows a general overview of users who installed but there's no drill-down or detailed view (e.g. which country they're installing from). Again, I understand that you could install google analytics but I'm trying to see if there are any other built-in tools provided by Google.

Comment: If you decide to go with Google Analytics, try out [this JavaScript library](https://github.com/googlechrome/chrome-platform-analytics) I worked on, and file bugs on Github if you run into problems :)

However, please note that it is a violation of the [Google Analytics terms of service](http://www.google.com/analytics/terms/us.html) to collect personal information, such as names: "You will not (and will not allow any third party to) use the Service to track, collect or upload any data that personally identifies an individual (such as a name, email address or billing information)"

Comment: Thanks @MatrixFrog! This was something I was hoping to come across to make integrating Google Analytics into packaged apps much easier!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there isn't. It would be a serious privacy violation if that were possible to do without individual user consent.

Comment: Ah, so it's definitely limited then. Thanks for the answer.